# Issues getting gsutil to use the gcloud activated service account

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get a service account which I have activated via gcloud auth login to be picked up by gsutil.  The big query command line tool bq is picking it up fine.

The order of operations I am following:

First:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file snip.json snip@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

This results in the output:
**Activated service account credentials for [snip@developer.gserviceaccount.com]**

Second:
I confirm the credential is active by:

```
gcloud auth list
```

Which results in: 
**Credentialed accounts:
 - snip@developer.gserviceaccount.com (active)...

Third:
I see if bq tools picks it up:

```
bq ls
```

Which correctly lists the dataset in my project.

Fourth:
I try gsutil against my bucket.  I have added my service account user as an owner to this bucket to ensure it has permissions.

```
gsutil ls gs://snip
```

This results in: a long wait, then eventually:
**You are attempting to access protected data with no configured
credentials. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
and sign up for an account, and then run the "gcloud auth login"
command to configure gsutil to use these credentials.**

Then I use the debug command:

```
gsutil -D
```

The output:

```
gsutil version: 4.11
checksum: snip (OK)
boto version: 2.30.0
python version: 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2014, 18:11:42) [GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)]
OS: Linux 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64
multiprocessing available: True
using cloud sdk: True
config path: no config found
gsutil path: /home/blah/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil
compiled crcmod: False
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
Command being run: /home/blah/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil -o GSUtil:default_project_id=snip -D
config_file_list: []
config: [('debug', '0'), ('working_dir', '/mnt/pyami'),'https_validate_certificates', 'true'), ('debug', '0'), ('working_dir', '/mnt/pyami'), ('default_project_id', 'snip')]
```

After this, if I add my own user id to the credential store via gcloud auth login, gsutil ls gs://snip works fine.  If I then switch the service account to be active instead of my user id (using gcloud config set account) it then doesn't work again - I get the same error message as above.

Last piece of info - I am running this on my own VM, not within GCE.

Comment: Hey fyi, I installed PyOpenSSL and switched to p12.  That worked fine, but JSON still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the issue. It seems to be happening only with JSON key files. Google is aware of this issue as per [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=162). Until it's resolved I'd recommend either authenticating using a P12 key file, or to add the default project service account as an owner on the bucket you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize the service account on the bucket from the cloud console click the "Edit bucket permission" and then add a permission for the email address of the service account.

[image]

Comment: Hi aqquadro - Thanks but I already had done this step.  I had given the service account owner privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I am not sure this is the answer to the question (please let me know and I will delete it), but seeing that there is no accepted answer for this and the two answers I see didn't solve the issue for me, here is what fixed the `gsutil` issue for me:

I re-initialized `gcloud` on the project level via the console shell (click the `>_` icon in the top right of the console to get the shell), then run something like this:
`user@direct-topic-1234:~$ gcloud init`

It will ask you a bunch of questions. I think choosing "Re-initialize this configuration [cloudshell-[#]] with new settings" was key, but I am not 100% sure.

After I finished that `gsutil` started to work. I was doing something different, but I am hoping this will help with this question. I was doing:

`gsutil mv gs://bucketname/filename instance-name:/a/path/filename`

(In the above, I am moving `filename` file from a project bucket to an instance `instance-name` and directory `/a/path/`.)

Mid-way down this link there is some helpful info:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets

This fixed `gsutil` for me! (I think it worked because before doing the above, my `gsutil` was configured for a zone that my bucket and instance were not in.)